# Email validation, Am I doing the right thing?

Tags: php

I am writing some PHP code where I end it with a email validation checking. Can someone review it and confirm if it's a good solution?

```
<?php
function isTrue($var) {
    return (isset($var)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function len($str) {
    $i;
    for($i=0; isTrue($str[$i]); $i++) {
        /* count me */
    }
    return $i;
}

function parsMe($str) {
    $at; $dot; $isvalid=0; $isnotvalid=0;
    for ( $at=0; isTrue($str[$at]); $at++) {
        if ( $str[$at] == "@" ) {
            for ( $dot=$at+1; isTrue($str[$dot]); $dot++ ) {
                if ( $str[$dot] == "." ) $isvalid += 1;
                if ( $str[$dot] =="@" || $str[len($str)-1] == "@" || $str[len($str)-1] == "." ) {
                    die("Error email entered");
                }
            }
        }
        if ( $str[$at] != "@" ) {
            $isnotvalid+=1;
        }
    }

    /* exit cond */
    if ( $isnotvalid == len($str)  ) die("Error mail usage");
    else if ( $isvalid == 0 ) die("Error mail");
    else echo "Mail is OK ";
}

$eml = "dotdot@com.";

parsMe($eml);
?>
```

`parsMe()` should produce error.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit for this.

Comment: `function isTrue($var) {` --- where did you read about that!? o_O And about `$at; $dot;` :-S

Comment: @zerkms: Perhaps [here](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/IsTrue().aspx).

Comment: it`s just excersise, I am doing, not an official validator... just asking if I am getting right at PHP or if I am missing something.

Comment: @Ilian Zapryanov: to be clear all your code is one big mistake

Comment: Just use `isset()` instead, or `!empty()` if it's from a form.

Comment: `function len($str) {` --- omg :-S Please say you just trolling us and have written that code just for fun

Comment: Did you consider learning some better web language, like http://opalang.org/ ? PHP is old stuff, even if it is very common...

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: c and c++ are old stuff as well. Please don't say "better" when you cannot prove that

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I`ll give it a try... I know PHP is old stuff but just had no idea what do I need for serverside programming..

Comment: @zerkms I  accept that mocking, I am a complete noob in PHP and I am programming less than a year and mainly on Python and C. I am just trying to gain some knowledge from experts and if you have better opinion than that, please tell me do I have to learn PHP to do some serverside code or I can use some other languages?

Comment: your code will say that $eml = "dotdot@.q"; is valid. use regex to check validity of email address, or, you can use Lawrence's answer.

Comment: @Ilian Zapryanov: php is good enough for web and your problem is that you're trying to apply your habits from another programming languages in php. That's just wrong. You see the difference between your 20 lines of messy code and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9051916/251311? That's what php about - there are a lot of functions to do various things, you don't need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @zerkms OK, I`ll reconsider that note and  will focus on the good ready parts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are [built in functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for checking validity of emails:

```
<?php 
$email ='dotdot@com';
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
 echo "E-mail is not valid";
}else{
 echo "E-mail is valid";
}
?>
```